# How to wrap with adjacent tag with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to do the following using beautifulsoup but I do not know how.

There is an html file like the following.

```
<img src="00001.jp">
<figcaption>caption string1</figcaption>

<img src="00002.jp">

<img src="00003.jp">
<figcaption>caption string3</figcaption>
```

I want to convert this html as follows.

```
<figure>
  <img src="00001.jp">
  <figcaption>caption string1</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <img src="00002.jp">
</figure>

<figure>
  <img src="00003.jp">
  <figcaption>caption string3</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If the next to the img tag is a figcaption tag, enclose it with a figure tag together.
And if it's different, I want to enclose only img tag with figure tag.

I understand that it is possible to enclose only the img tag with a figure tag with the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<img src="00001.jp">
<figcaption>caption string1</figcaption>

<img src="00002.jp">

<img src="00003.jp">
<figcaption>caption string3</figcaption>"

content = BeautifulSoup(html)

for img_tag in content.find_all('img'):
  img_tag.wrap(content.new_tag('figure'))
```

However, I do not know how to detect that the next tag is a figcaption tag.
Also, I do not know whether to enclose img tag and figcaption with figure tag together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it in a single line, but you can do it with a couple of minor changes:

```
for img_tag in content.find_all('img'):          
    fig = content.new_tag('figure')
    img_tag.wrap(fig)

    next_node = img_tag.find_next() 
    if next_node and next_node.name == 'figcaption':        
        fig.append(next_node)

print(content)
```

You'd need to first create the `figure` tag and keep a reference to it and *then* wrap the `image` tag. After that, use `img_tag.find_next()` to get the next sibling and check if it is a `figcaption` tag. If yes, append that tag as a child of the `figure` tag.

It helps to understand that all changes are made in place.

This code will give:

```
<figure>
   <img src="00001.jp"/>
   <figcaption>caption string1</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure><img src="00002.jp"/></figure>
<figure>
   <img src="00003.jp"/>
   <figcaption>caption string3</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)